# How to properly replace disk RAID1 with uefi boot

Tags: hard-drive, debian, raid, grub, uefi

im facing situation when i need to replace hdd with uefi boot. Never done before. Standard procedure with legacy boot (MBR) is okay but im not sure how to do that when UEFI is on server.

Server have 2 disks with raid partitions but own EFI system partition

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8EFEBE36-0712-4A61-BB1E-C698A8F7184D

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048     249855     247808  121M EFI System
/dev/sda2    249856    1249279     999424  488M BIOS boot
/dev/sda3   1249280   59842559   58593280   28G Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  59842560 7038615551 6978772992  3.3T Linux RAID

----

fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8EFEBE36-0712-4A61-BB1E-C698A8F7184D

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048     249855     247808  121M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    249856    1249279     999424  488M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb3   1249280   59842559   58593280   28G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  59842560 7038615551 6978772992  3.3T Linux RAID

----

Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid1 sdb4[1] sda4[0]
      3489254400 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 8/26 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      29279232 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

What i want to do ?
/dev/sda is failing and need to be replaced.

Before everything -
Backup EFI partition

```
umount /boot/efi
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=4M of=/root/EFI_PARTITITON.img
```

Remove disk from md

```
mdamd /dev/md0 -f /dev/sda3
mdamd /dev/md0 -r /dev/sda3
mdamd /dev/md1 -f /dev/sda4
mdamd /dev/md1 -r /dev/sda4
```

Physicaly replace disks

clone partitions and restore efi partition from DD img

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda
dd if=/root/EFI_PARTITITON.img bs=4M of=/dev/sda1
mount /boot/efi
```

Add RAID partitions back to md

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda3
mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda4
```

Update grub

```
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Is that procedure okay ? Or whats the proper way how to replace disks in that setup ? Thanks for answer and have a nice day.